# Mass-energy equivalence - old notation

Tags: special-relativity, notation, mass-energy, history

Einstein originally gave the formula as

$$M = \mu + \frac{E_0}{c^2}.\tag{17}$$

In which $\mu$ was the mass of the system. [Today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence), we more commonly get taught that the energy is in relation to the square root (written with modern notation as):

$$E = \sqrt{m_0^2c^4 + p^2c^2}.$$

The first equation does not generally follow the second, since $a + b \ne \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$?

Of course, it is true that $a + b = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ can be true if for the rest system if $b=0$ - is this the kind of idea that was being used?

Comment: Which of his papers has the first formula?

Comment: In fear of the paper not being in english, you can follow the same relationship in the nomenclature section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-mass_equivalence

Comment: It is equation (17) in this (translated) paper: https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/300

Comment: thank you. Other than that, any idea's how history went from the first equation., to taking the square root?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make sense of $M=\mu+E_0/c^2$ because as far as I can tell from the paper, he is using $M$ to mean relativistic mass, $\mu$ to mean rest mass, and $E_0$ to mean rest energy. But with that those meanings this is wrong. He also says “we can arbitrarily assign the zero-point of $E_0$”, which is something else I don’t understand. In general, I have found that reading old papers is often extremely confusing compared with the relative clarity of modern expositions.

Comment: The only way the equation makes sense to me is if $E_0$ is the kinetic energy, but I find nothing in the paper that indicates this is so.

Comment: BTW, in my opinion you should think of the second equation in the form $m^2=E^2-\mathbf{p}^2$ (in units with $c=1$), which says “mass is the Lorentz-invariant length of the energy-momentum four-vector $(E, \mathbf{p})$”. This stresses the Minkowski geometry of spacetime, the relativity of energy and momentum, and the absoluteness of mass, all in one beautifully simple geometric equation.

Comment: Yes is just as posing v=0 to get E=mc2. In that original formula rest mass is the fraction, mu is the gain of inertia and m the relativistic mass. But I can't see in the link how mu was introduced. What I do here is based on what we know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [§ 9 of his paper](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol2-trans/300), Einstein defined the kinetic energy (eq. 14) as:

$\frac{\mu c^{2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{q^{2}}{c^{2}}}}+const$

where $\mu$ is the invariant rest mass. In § 11 he went further and defined the total energy of a uniformly moving system, consisting of the above kinetic energy as well as the additional internal energy $E_0$ (work, thermodynamic energy, etc) as measured in its rest system, obtaining the equation (16a):

$E=\left(\mu+\frac{E_{0}}{c^{2}}\right)\frac{c^{2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{q^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$

from which he concludes that the (invariant) mass of the system is given by (17):

$m=\mu+\frac{E_{0}}{c^{2}}$

In modern terminology, $E_{0}/c^{2}$ is the invariant mass of the additional internal energy, $\mu$ the invariant mass without additional internal energy, and $m$ is the invariant total mass or total rest energy (there is no "relativistic mass" involved in Einstein's example). Using $m$ in (16a), the relativistic energy equation obtains its modern form

$E=\frac{mc^{2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{q^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$

Note, that Einstein's treatment is based on Planck's [previous treatment in 1907](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Dynamics_of_Moving_Systems) (to whom Einstein refers in his paper as well), who defined invariant mass $M$ as:

$M=\frac{E_{0}+pV_{0}}{c^{2}}$

with $pV_{0}$ as the additional internal energy in terms of pressure and volume.

Now let's talk about the history of the energy-momentum relation: We simply take the above equation for relativistic energy, as well as the equation for relativistic momentum (given by [Planck in 1906](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:The_Principle_of_Relativity_and_the_Fundamental_Equations_of_Mechanics) and [in 1907](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Dynamics_of_Moving_Systems) as well as Einstein in [1907](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Dynamics_of_Moving_Systems)), which have the form in modern notation

$E=\frac{mc^{2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$ and $p=\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$

Then we solve $p$ for $v$, inserting the result into $E$, which gives after some algebra and simplification:

$E=\sqrt{m^{2}c^{4}+p^{2}c^{2}}$

Comment: Very clear and concise.